# Hybrid mobile application in cordova no internet connection issue

Tags: cordova, mobile, web-applications

I have already developed an application in cordova and everything works fine up till now. The problem is with `Internet Connection` i have detected the internet connection on app launch and showed a message of `no internet connection` and closed the application at that time. But my question is what if internet connection goes away after the app is loaded in `webview` if that happens everything on the page will go away and there will be a message as we see usually 'Web page not available'.

Is that any solution available for this.?

Comment: you can show your own custom message in case of mobiles.......for web also you can do that but you need to restrict the browser for dont not perform actions on that page.....if it happens then you will get defaukt msg

Comment: I appreciate your prompt reply @Sa E Chowdary but i didn't actually understand what you mean to say, can you please elaborate.

Comment: show a modal box when ever internet goes off.....make sure user cannot access application untill the network conncetd and close after recognizing network

Comment: You are absolutely right, but i have made this in cordova that means its "web based" so how can i detect that internet connection is not there.? Everything is right now working through web and when that goes off how we even trigger an event. Please share your ideas.

Comment: i am little confused now....up to now i am thinking that we are discussing about hybrid mobile app based on cordova.....what do you mean by web based??

Comment: If you see the cordova website they say this "Mobile apps with HTML, CSS & JS" so i guess these things can only make web based applications not "Native Applications" am i right.?

Comment: And what i mean to say here it that, i have created an applications which is created in HTML5, CSS, JS and now i want to show no internet connection when connection goes off. Please share your knowledge.